# Optimizing MongoDB Query Get TotalRecord in Node.js

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

I have a MongoDB query in my Node.js application that I would like to optimize for better performance. The query looks like this:

```
const CampaignStepHistoryList = await CampaignStepHistory.aggregate([
    {
        $match: {ClientID: new ObjectId(ClientID), UserID: new ObjectId(UserID), IsSentMail: true,
    },
    },
      {
        $addFields: {
          MailSentDateByTimeZones_temp: {
            $dateToString: {
              format: "%Y-%m-%d",
              date: "$MailSentDateByTimeZone",
            },
          },
        },
      },
      {
        $match:{
          MailSentDateByTimeZones_temp: { $gte: "2024-01-01", $lte: "2024-03-21",
          },
        }
   },
      
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "campaigns",
      let: {
        flag: false,
        cID: "$CampaignID",
        cId: "$ClientID",
        uID: "$UserID",
      },
      pipeline: [
        {
          $match: {
            $expr: {
              $and: [{ $eq: ["$_id", "$$cID"] },
                { $eq: ["$UserID", "$$uID"] },
                { $eq: ["$ClientID", "$$cId"] },
              ],},},},
      ],
      as: "C",
    },
  },
  {
    $unwind: {
      path: "$C",
      preserveNullAndEmptyArrays: false,
    },
  },
  {
    $count: "totalRecords"
}
  
])
```

To get the total record count in a collection with 33 million records in MongoDB
How to get that much records in zero sec.
i have tried by indexing so it is not possible in zero sec.

Answer (score 0):

It's difficult to assess database performance without knowing your data model, but heres a shot at it:

```html
const CampaignStepHistoryList = await CampaignStepHistory.aggregate([
   {
      $match: {
         ClientID: new ObjectId(ClientID), 
         UserID: new ObjectId(UserID), 
         IsSentMail: true,
         MailSentDateByTimeZone: { $gte: new Date("2024-01-01"), $lte: new Date("2024-03-21")}
      },
   },
   {
      $lookup: {
         from: "campaigns",
         let: {
           flag: false,
           cID: "$CampaignID",
           cId: "$ClientID",
           uID: "$UserID",
         },
         pipeline: [
            {
               $match: {
                  $expr: {
                     $and: [
                        { $eq: ["$_id", "$cID"] },
                        { $eq: ["$UserID", "$uID"] },
                        { $eq: ["$ClientID", "$cId"] },
                     ],
                  },
               },
            },
         ],
         as: "C",
      },
   },
   {
      $unwind: {
         path: "$C",
         preserveNullAndEmptyArrays: false,
      },
   },
   {
      $count: "totalRecords"
   }
])
```

Likely to be very minor, you're better off better indexing your data more effectively, for the lookup. If you're solely looking to count the data, you're best off storing the count on it's own row and using the unique properties of your query as it's key